# Pandas how to group a DataFrame every 1 year starting form a custom month?

Tags: python, pandas, pd.grouper

I want to group a DataFrame every 1 year, or 12 month starts, beginning from July 1st. I prefer using Grouper. I am not sure why this code works for 7 days, i.e., '7D' but not for '12MS' or '1Y'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
#%% Group by 7days starting from December 30th 1999
start, end = '2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2000-01-07 23:00:00'
rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='1H')
ts = pd.Series(np.ones(len(rng)), index=rng)

grouper = pd.Grouper(freq="7D", origin=pd.Timestamp("1999-12-30"))
grouped = ts.groupby(grouper)
print(grouped.apply(len))


#%% Group by 12 months starting from July 1st 1999
start, end = '2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2001-12-31 23:00:00'
rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='1H')
ts = pd.Series(np.ones(len(rng)), index=rng)

grouper = pd.Grouper(freq="12MS", origin=pd.Timestamp("1999-07-01"))
grouped = ts.groupby(grouper)
print(grouped.apply(len))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `freq='AS'` in your code.

```
grouper = pd.Grouper(freq="AS", origin=pd.Timestamp("1999-07-01"))
```

For full list of offsets you can refer here - [offset-aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

Comment: The problem is the first year should contain values for only 6 months. Your code won't do that! it gives this:

2000-01-01    8784
2001-01-01    8760
Freq: AS-JAN, dtype: int64

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

`grouper = pd.Grouper(freq="A-JUN")`

A-JUN means "annual frequency, anchored end of June."